# When to use index join?

Tags: sql

I was wondering what is the best scenario to use index join when joining two tables besides nested loop join and merge-sort join?

Comment: This is determined by the query optimizer.  Although most databases support hints for such things, it is better to depend on the optimizer.

Answer (score 2):

Usually you don't tell the SQL engine how to actually execute the join.  The query optimizer will parse your query, and then examine the stats for the tables you are joining and it will choose whether to do merge, nested loops, etc.  The query optimizer determines what indexes can/should be used at this time as well, based on the lowest predicted cost of each possible algorithm.